# Subclassing, extending or wrapping Node.js 'request' module to enhance response

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm trying to extend `request` in order to hijack and enhance its `response` and other 'body' params. In the end, I want to add some convenience methods for my API:

```
var myRequest = require('./myRequest');
myRequest.get(function(err, hijackedResponse, rows) {
    console.log(hijackedResponse.metadata)
    console.log(rows)
    console.log(rows.first)
});
```

According to the Node docs on `inherits`, I thought I could make it work (and using the `EventEmitter` example in the docs works OK). I tried getting it to work using @Trott's suggestion but realized that for my use case it's probably not going to work:

```
// myRequest.js
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var Request = require("request").Request;

function MyRequest(options) {
    Request.call(this, options);
}

inherits(MyRequest, Request);

MyRequest.prototype.pet = function() {
    console.log('purr')
}

module.exports = MyRequest;
```

I've been toying with `extend` as well, hoping that I could find a way to intercept request's `onRequestResponse` prototype method, but I'm drawing blanks:

```
var extend = require('extend'),
    request = require("request")

function myResponse() {}

extend(myResponse, request)

// maybe some magic happens here?

module.exports = myResponse
```

---

#### Ended up with:

```
var extend = require('extend'),
    Ok = require('objectkit').Ok

function MyResponse(response) {
    var rows = Ok(response.body).getIfExists('rows');
    extend(response, {
        metadata: extend({}, response.body),
        rows: rows
    });
    response.first = (function() {
        return rows[0]
    })();
    response.last = (function() {
        return rows[rows.length - 1] || rows[0]
    })();
    delete response.metadata.rows
    return response;
}

module.exports = MyResponse
```

Keep in mind in this example, I cheated and wrote it all inside the `.get()` method. In my final wrapper module, I'm actually taking `method` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED to answer the edited question:

Here's a rough template for the contents of your `myResponse.js`. It only implements `get()`. But as a bare bones, this-is-how-this-sort-of-thing-can-be-done demo, I hope it gets you going.

```
var request = require('request');

var myRequest = {};

myRequest.get = function (callback) {
    // hardcoding url for demo purposes only
    // could easily get it as a function argument, config option, whatever...
    request.get('http://www.google.com/', function (error, response, body) {
        var rows = [];
        // only checking error here but you might want to check the response code as well
        if (!error) {
            // mess with response here to add metadata. For example...
            response.metadata = 'I am awesome';

            // convert body to rows however you process that. I'm just hardcoding.
            // maybe you'll use JSON.parse() or something.
            rows = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

            // You can add properties to the array if you want.
            rows.first = 'I am first! a a a a';
        }

        // now fire the callback that the user sent you...
        callback(error, response, rows);
    });
};

module.exports = myRequest;
```

ORIGINAL answer:

Looking at [the source code for the `Request` constructor](https://github.com/request/request/blob/478e0c2766fab310b199c1b0b07d7a2197f070f1/request.js#L105-L141), it requires an `options` object that in turn requires a `uri` property.

So you need to specify such an object as the second parameter in your `call()`:

```
Request.call(this, {uri: 'http://localhost/'});
```

You likely don't want to hard code `uri` like that inside the constructor. You probably want the code to look something more like this:

```
function MyRequest(options) {
    Request.call(this, options);
}

...

var myRequest = new MyRequest({uri: 'http://localhost/'});
```

For your code to work, you will also need to move `util.inherits()` above the declaration for `MyRequest.prototype.pat()`. It appears that `util.inherits()` clobbers any existing prototype methods of the first argument.

Comment: I've updated the answer to hopefully show how to do that a little more explicitly.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your use case, so apologies if this is (as the quip goes) not even wrong, but you could use the fact that `request.get()` is a factory function. `var req1 = request.get('http://example.com/foo');` and `var req2 = request.get('http://example.com/bar');` Then do whatever with `req1` and `req2` like `req1.pipe();` or `req2.on('data', callback);`.

Comment: Yeah, I should make my use case a little more clear. I'm trying to hijack the response object and extend it with some other information unique to the API I'm calling, or even add a 4th property on the return (`function(err, resp, body, metadata)`)

Comment: You might have an easier time writing a wrapper around `request` rather than trying to inherit from `Request`. (Again, I don't know the details, so feel free to ignore.)

Comment: Updated the answer with something closer to what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Ahhh I see - override each individual method on request instead. That could work. Giving it a shot now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Adding my solution to OP.